# SQL Server 2008 NOT IN() seems to fail

Tags: sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, in-function

I am building a suggestive tagging system (sounds seedy), I pass in a string to the db and if there is a match it sends back that tag. I want to stop duplicate tags, so if one tag is WEB, I only want it to be returned once. So if I had WEB as a tag and then add WEEKLY, typing "WE" doesn't bring up WEB for a second time as a suggestion.

But, seem to be not working. I send the current tags and use NOT IN() to remove any duplicates. Below is the SP code:

```
SELECT  TOP 1 t.vTagName As vTagName
FROM        Tags t
WHERE       t.vTagName LIKE @vTagName+'%'
AND         t.nTagPortalId = @nPortalId
AND         t.vTagName NOT IN(@vCurrentTags)
ORDER BY    vTagName ASC
```

And this is what get's passed in:

```
EXEC GetTagSuggest 'We','Web,Print,Design,Advertising,Revenue'
```

The response to this query is vTagName = Web. Obviously, this is not a correct result as it should be vTagName LIKE "We" NOT IN "Web, etc..."..

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Erland Sommarskog has a good [article](http://www.sommarskog.se/dyn-search-2005.html) on various ways to perform these types of search

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The IN statement doesn't work like that.

What you will have to do is

```
t.vTagName not in ('Web','Print','Design','Advertising','Revenue')
```

Having it in one variable won't work in that case.

Comment: Which is what I said in my reply with "split out the strings".

Comment: To pass in the current tags as a split string I send in this (from classic asp): EXEC GetTagSuggest 'Web','''Web'',''Create'''. That, when selected, returns: 'Web','Create'. But when passed in like this: t.vTagName NOT IN(@vCurrentTags), it still doesn't work. How in SQL could I split the string?

Comment: @randolph: I understand that, but I required a little more information that one line :)

Comment: If you cannot split the string, perhaps look at the dynamic SQL method I described.

Answer (score 2):

You need to split out the strings, or convert the entire SQL statement to dynamic SQL.

EDIT:

Split out variables per the other example, or do dynamic SQL.

**This is not best practice**, but is simply to give you an idea:

```
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max) = 'SELECT  TOP 1 t.vTagName As vTagName '
SELECT @sql = @sql + 'FROM  Tags t '
SELECT @sql = @sql + 'WHERE t.vTagName LIKE ' + @vTagName + '% '
SELECT @sql = @sql + 'AND   t.nTagPortalId = ' + @nPortalId + ' '
SELECT @sql = @sql + 'AND   t.vTagName NOT IN(' + @vCurrentTags + ') '
SELECT @sql = @sql + 'ORDER BY  vTagName ASC'

EXEC sp_executesql @sql, @vTagName, @nPortalId, @vCurrentTags
```